# Solving recurrence relation using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, recurrence

Good evening, experts

I want to solve recurrence equation using mathematica,

```
x(n) = x(n − 1) + n 
for n > 0, 
    x(0) = 0
```

And i need to find x(1), x(2), x,(3)

This is my input and it gives me errors

```
n > 0
a[0] := 0
RSolve[x == a[n - 1] + n, a[n], n]
```

How can I rewrite the equation using the mathematica?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of this very pattern is the 2nd example in [the documentation for RSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RSolve.html):

> Include a boundary condition:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= RSolve[{a[n + 1] - 2 a[n] == 1, a[0] == 1}, a[n], n]
>
> Out[1]= {{a[n] -> -1 + 2^(1 + n)}}
> ```

For your problem, that'd be:

```
In[1]:= RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + n, a[0] == 0}, a[n], n]

Out[1]= {{a[n] -> 1/2 n (1 + n)}}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, how can write that n>0? or if want to specify that n>2?

Comment: Mathematica will in general deduce that automatically based on the boundary conditions provided. If you get an instance where it doesn't (unlikely for basic recurrences), you should post a new question about that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + n, a[0] == 0}, a[n], n]
```

Remove the following:

```
n > 0
a[0] := 0
```

`a[0] := 0` is a function definition.  `a` must not have associated definitions in order to work in `RSolve`

Comment: thanks for reply, how can write that n>0? or if want to specify that n>2?

Comment: @mydreamadsl Why do you need that? It wouldn't change the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find x(1), x(2), x(3), you can use `RecurrenceTable`:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == x[n - 1] + n, x[0] == 0}, x[n], {n, 3}]

{0,1,3,6}
```

x(1)=1, x(2)=3, x(3)=6